# Updating Appreg in Azure with MsGraph API

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

Using C# Dotnet 7 code that calls GraphAPI v5.x, I create a new AppReg in Azure with the necessary information, and this works perfectly.
I then try to add a ClientSecret to my new AppReg using the command from the Microsoft site

```
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 5.x

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Applications.Item.AddPassword.AddPasswordPostRequestBody
{
    PasswordCredential = new PasswordCredential
    {
        DisplayName = "Password friendly name",
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Applications["Myapplication-id"].AddPassword.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

I get the error code : {"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown."}

I extract the code and message from the catch and obtain the following information:

Error.Code = Request_ResourceNotFound

Error.Message = Resource 'Myapplication-id' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

As soon as you try to access or modify information using the following code:

```
  var result = await graphClient.Applications["Myapplication-id"].xxxx => any method
```

I'm getting the same error.
I have repeatedly checked the validity and accuracy of the value of the Myapplication-id, it's a good one.

Has anyone ever solved this problem?

I tried to load the info on my appreg via this

```
var result = await graphClient.Applications.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "appId eq 'Myapplication-id'";
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "displayName" };
        requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
    });
```

I can see all the properties and add a password like this :

```
Application requestBody = new()
        {
           PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>
            {

                new()
                {
                    DisplayName = "Password friendly name",
                    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2),
                    KeyId = Guid.NewGuid()
                }

            }
        };



        var result = await graphClient.Applications["Myapplication-id"].PatchAsync(requestBody);
```

same result, nothing !

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) declares that you can address the application using either its `id` or `appId` but it doesn't work.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}
```

works, but

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{app_id}
```

doesn't work. I can confirm that it worked for some time but know it doesn't.

As a workaround you can try to filter your app by `appId`

```
var result = await graphClient.Applications.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"appId eq '{appId}'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "id" };
});

var app = result.Value.FirstOrDefault();
```

Use `Id` in the next call

```
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Applications.Item.AddPassword.AddPasswordPostRequestBody
{
    PasswordCredential = new PasswordCredential
    {
        DisplayName = "Password friendly name",
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Applications[app .Id].AddPassword.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: Top, it works, by testing 100 times you become 'crazy' in the end. In my tests, I also did this, except in the ".Select". Thank you for your reply